# Wiremock url matching - "null. When using a regex, "?" should be "\\?". URLs must start with a /"

Tags: regex, wiremock

I have a urlPattern:

```
"urlPattern" : "^\/blah\/players\/1000\/game\/tickets\\?drawFrom=(.*)&drawTo=(.*)&take=10&skip=0"
```

But when trying to match them, I get "Request not matched" and this error

```
<<<<< null. When using a regex, "?" should be "\\?". URLs must start with a /
```

The url regex is also showing up in the terminal as

```
^\/blah\/players\/1000\/game\/tickets\?drawFrom=(.*)&drawTo=(.*)&take=10&skip=0
```

I have used `\\?` instead of `\?` so I'm stuck on what the problem could be. I've also used almost identical regex in other places that's working fine.

EDIT: This is what the actual request looks like

```
/blah/players/1000/game/tickets?drawFrom=2018-01-01&drawTo=2018-02-02&take=10&skip=0
```

Comment: Can you post the request as well? And if there is a closest match output in terminal? Queries can be confusing with regexes, so without seeing what you're requesting, it might be difficult to see why the match is missing.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. This is what the request looks like.
/blah/players/1000/game/tickets?drawFrom=2018-01-01&drawTo=2018-02-02&take=10&skip=0

Comment: Hmm... Two things:
1. Try setting the url to start with... "/blah/...". I don't think you need to escape the `/` or start the string with a `^`. I think this is the actual relevant part of the error you're getting.
2. If that doesn't work, try matching on the url and query separately. You can use urlPath/urlPathPattern to check the url, and then a separate "queryParameters": { "drawFrom": { "matches": ".*" } } (sorry for poor formatting)

Comment: Ah, starting it without the escape and the ^ worked. Thank you. You can post it as an answer and I'll flag it as the accepted answer if you'd like :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your error is because the URL does not need the preceding `^` because WireMock knows that the URL begins with a `/`. Additionally, you do not need to escape the `/` characters.

This should work:

```
"urlPattern" : "/blah/players/1000/game/tickets\\?drawFrom=(.*)&drawTo=(.*)&take=10&skip=0"
```